# Soap webervices Api for retrieving relationship data from sugarCrm in java

Tags: java, php, soap, sugarcrm

I have two modules in sugarcrm(version 6.5.3):

1. Affiliates
2. Address.

Affiliate has an address mapped by one-to-one relationship. Is there a soap api method in the Java Client by which I can retrieve affiliate data along with its mapped address. If not how do I write one.

Or is there any way by which i can get the data from relation ship table which contains id of both the modules.

Is there any api by which i can retrieve relationship data. If possible please provide me any example where situation like mine is handled.

Answer (score 0):

There is the API Method get_relationships() does this solve you problem or did I misunderstood it

Comment: Ah in the SOAP client you have to add the corresponding method. Sorry I didn't check that. I use the Java REST client and added the method calls I needed there. I would suggest you do the same .-)